# Spring JPA - Persisting @ManyToMany entity - duplicated entity error

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, many-to-many

I need help with my use case.
I have an `Order` entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "orders")
public class Order {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = {
    CascadeType.PERSIST,
    CascadeType.MERGE
    })
    @JoinTable(name = "inconsistent_orders",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "order_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "inconsistency_id")
    )
    private Set<OrderInconsistency> inconsistencies;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Set<OrderInconsistency> getInconsistencies() {
        return inconsistencies;
    }

    //getters and setters ommitted for brevity

    public void setInconsistencies(Set<OrderInconsistency> inconsistencies) {
        this.inconsistencies = inconsistencies;
        this.inconsistencies.forEach(i -> i.setOrders(List.of(this)));
    }

    //hashcode and equals ommitted for brevity
}
```

and a `OrderInconsistency` entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "order_inconsistencies")
public class OrderInconsistency {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    private String id;

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "description")
    private String description;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "inconsistencies")
    private List<Order> orders = new ArrayList<>();

    public OrderInconsistency() {
    }

    public OrderInconsistency(String id, String description) {
        Assert.notNull(id, "El id de la inconsistencia no puede ser null");
        this.id = id.replaceAll(" ", "_").toUpperCase();
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public List<Order> getOrders() {
        return orders;
    }

    public void setOrders(List<Order> orders) {
        this.orders = orders;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

        OrderInconsistency that = (OrderInconsistency) o;

        return id.equals(that.id);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return id.hashCode();
    }
}
```

My Many to Many table:

```
CREATE TABLE `inconsistent_orders`
(
    `order_id`         INT(11)     NOT NULL,
    `inconsistency_id` VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`order_id`, `inconsistency_id`),
    FOREIGN KEY (`order_id`) REFERENCES `orders` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY (`inconsistency_id`) REFERENCES `order_inconsistencies` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

The idea is that the `Order` is the parent of this relationship, so when I save the `Order`, it should save its inconsistencies (if any).

Order inconsistencies don't change once they're created. For example, if a new `Order` gets saved and it has an `OrderInconsistency` with the ID `TOTALS_DONT_MATCH`, and an inconsistency with that ID doesn't already exist, JPA should create it before saving the order and then add it to the `Set` of inconsistencies in that order.

In the future, other orders could potentially have that Inconsistency and since it already exists in the DB, JPA shouldn't create it and simply add it to the many to many table `inconsistent_orders`.

However, the problem I'm facing, is that even though I'm manually assigning an ID that already exists to a manually created instance of `OrderInconsistency`, JPA attempts to insert it thus resulting in a duplicate entry error.

**To summarise, the first time I save an order, it works and the `OrderInconsistency` gets saved. If another `Order` gets saved and it has that same `OrderInconsistency`, JPA attempts to insert it even though it already exists and fails**.

For example

```
@Transactional
public ValidatedOrderDTO saveConsistentOrder(Order order) {
    boolean consistentOrder = true;
    var orderInconsistencies = new HashSet<OrderInconsistency>();
    for (OrderValidationService validationService : orderValidationServices) {
        ValidationResult validationResult = validationService.validate(order);
        if (!validationResult.isValid()) {
            // this returns a manually created instance of OrderConsistency with an ID that already exists in the DB
            OrderInconsistency inconsistency = validationResult.getOrderInconsistency();   
            orderInconsistencies.add(inconsistency);
            consistentOrder = false;
        }
    }
    order.setInconsistencies(orderInconsistencies);
    ordersDAO.save(order); //here, JPA attempts to INSERT the OrderInconsistency even though it already exists in DB
    return new ValidatedOrderDTO(consistentOrder, consistenciesDescription);
}
```

The solution I came up with is to have a `OrderInconsistencyDAO` and manually `findById` the Inconsistency and if it exists, add it to the `Order`, if not, assign the new instance to the `Order`. I don't understand why that works and if it's the correct way to do it. Does it have something to do with managed and unmanaged entities?

Working example - **I don't understand why it works**

```
@Transactional
public ValidatedOrderDTO saveConsistentOrder(Order order) {
    boolean consistentOrder = true;
    var orderInconsistencies = new HashSet<OrderInconsistency>();
    for (OrderValidationService validationService : orderValidationServices) {
        ValidationResult validationResult = validationService.validate(order);
        if (!validationResult.isValid()) {
            OrderInconsistency inconsistency = validationResult.getOrderInconsistency();

            Optional<OrderInconsistency> orderInconsistencyOpt = orderInconsistenciesDAO.findById(inconsistency.getId());
            if (orderInconsistencyOpt.isEmpty()) {
                orderInconsistenciesDAO.save(inconsistency);
            } else {
                inconsistency = orderInconsistencyOpt.get();
            }

            orderInconsistencies.add(inconsistency);
            consistentOrder = false;
        }
    }
    order.setInconsistencies(orderInconsistencies);
    ordersDAO.save(order);
    return new ValidatedOrderDTO(consistentOrder, consistenciesDescription);
}
```

Comment: Could it be because in the second code snippet the value of the Order variable in OrderInconsistency has been set because it is obtained from the database and in the first when doing it manually, no?

Being a bidirectional relationship NM you must establish both properties, Order in OrderInconsistency and OrderInconsistency in Order

Comment: @JLazar0 the order is always set on `order.setInconsistencies(...)`. Even in the snippet that doesn't work.

Comment: at the moment ordersDAO.save (order) is executed in the snippet that does not work, the OrderInconsistency have id?

Comment: Yes, `validationResult.getOrderInconsistency()` always returns a an `OrderInconsistency` with an ID.